# I can't make the slash command half of the hybrid command sync. (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a simple text command set up to sync all of my commands in my discord bot. (discord.py) For some reason, only the text half of the hybrid command works. When I got to type `o.sync`, it says that 0 commands have been synced, but the `o.ping` command works. Are there any glaring mistakes that I'm missing?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class Survey(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Survey cog loaded.')

    @commands.command()
    async def sync(self, ctx) -> None:
        fmt = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)

        await ctx.send(
            f"Synced {len(fmt)} commands to the current guild."
        )

    @commands.command()
    async def unsync(self, ctx) -> None:
        ctx.bot.tree.clear_commands(guild=ctx.guild)
        sync_tree = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        await ctx.send(
            f"Unsynced {len(sync_tree)} commands to the current guild."
        )
        return

    @commands.hybrid_command(name='ping', with_app_command=True)
    async def help(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send("pong", ephemeral=True)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Survey(bot), guilds=[discord.Object(id=874842871801479208)])
```

The fact that the `o.ping` command shows that the hybrid command is functioning, but the slash command doesn't show up at all in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

try this is worked with me..

```
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def sync(ctx) -> None:
        synced = await ctx.bot.tree.sync()
        await ctx.send(
            f"Synced {len(synced)} commands to the current guild."
        )
        return
```

Comment: Would this sync globally or just to the guild the message was sent in?

Comment: guild only not globally
I used @commands.guild_only()